# Disallow and redirect user to a different page after social login in ASP.NET Core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I'm implementing authentication in ASP.NET Core with social providers using the authentication middleware (**no** Identity). Things are working with the following configuration:

```cs
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn = false;
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
    })
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "...";
        options.ClientSecret = "...";
        options.Events = new OAuthEvents
        {
            OnTicketReceived = ctx =>
            {
                ...
            }
        };
    });
```

When redirecting the user to the Google challenge and they sign in, my site successfully authenticates with cookie auth.

Now, I want greater control of what should happen when the user sign in. I want to verify a few requirements in `OnTicketReceived` and disallow the sign in with cookie auth in some cases.

Consider code like this for`OnTicketReceived`:

```cs
OnTicketReceived = ctx =>
{
    if (someRequirementNotMet)
    {
         // User should not be logged in and redirected to /login
         // CODE MISSING HERE!
    }

    if (someCondition)
    {
         // User should be logged in and redirected to /somepage
         ctx.ReturnUri = "/somepage";
         return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // User should be logged in and redirected to /someotherpage
    ctx.ReturnUri = "/someotherpage";
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

How would I achieve this? I've tried this:

```cs
ctx.ReturnUri = "/login";
return Task.CompletedTask;
```

inside the first `if`. But the user is logged in when redirected to `/login`. I've also tried to call `ctx.HandleResponse()` but this simply generates a blank result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how this can be solved:

```cs
OnTicketReceived = ctx =>
{
    if (someRequirementNotMet)
    {
         // User should not be logged in and redirected to /login
         ctx.HandleResponse();
         ctx.Response.Redirect("/login");
         return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    if (someCondition)
    {
         // User should be logged in and redirected to /somepage
         ctx.ReturnUri = "/somepage";
         return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // User should be logged in and redirected to /someotherpage
    ctx.ReturnUri = "/someotherpage";
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `ctx.HandleResponse(); ctx.Response.Redirect("...");` versus `ctx.ReturnUri = "...";` usage patterns?

Comment: I think you should create a new question about this.

Comment: If I redirect to the Microsoft Identity Logout page via `ctxt.Response.Redirect("/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut");` it results in an infinite loop because the Azure B2C thinks I'm still logged in and it goes back to the `OnTicketReceived` event.